# Why cant I get FIBONACCI NUMBERS starting from 0, 1, 1, 2.. and so forth?Solution in beginners format highly appreciated

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I should be able to call function (lets say) with an input of 3

fibonacciGenerator(3); and get [0,1,1] as the output

**CODE STARTS HERE**

```
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {     
    var fibNumSequence = [];
    var n1= 0; 
    var n2 = 1; 
    var nextTerm;
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        
       nextTerm = n1+n2;
       n1 = n2;
       n2 = nextTerm;
      
    
        fibNumSequence.push(n2);
       
    
    }
    
    return fibNumSequence;
    
}
    
fibonacciGenerator(n);
```

Comment: You don't put the initial `0` and `1` in the `fibNumSequence` array. Apart from that, the code is perfectly fine

Comment: It's a good idea to post your output and explain what you don't understand. A hint for you is that in your very first iteration of the loop `n1 = 0` and `n2 = 1` (1+0 = 1). The first element in your array needs to be 0 and not 1

Comment: `i <= n` makes the for loop execute `n+1` times (i=0, 1, 2, ..., n). You have to use `i < n` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that n1 is changed from "0" to "1" and is never pushed to the fibNumSequence array. Here is what happens in order:

1. you declare n1 as "0"
2. you declare n2 as "1"
3. nextTerm is set to "0 + 1"
4. n1 is set to "1" (value of nextTerm)
5. n2 is set to "1" (value of n1)
6. n2 is pushed to the array so fibNumSequence = [1]

and then the process repeats.

You can solve this by setting the fibNumSequence from the beginning to [0] and set the for loop like this, each loops adds the previous number from the array to the nextTerm variable. The "n-1" is to correct for the one number already in the array at the beginning.

```
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
  var fibNumSequence = [0];
  var nextTerm = 1;
  
  
  for (var i = 0; i < n -1 ; i++) {
    
    fibNumSequence.push(nextTerm);

    nextTerm = nextTerm + fibNumSequence[i];
  }
  return fibNumSequence;
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(5))
```

Comment: hello, thank you for taking the time to explain what went wrong however I still get an output of [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]  instead of [0, 1, 1, 2, 3] for an input of 5 using your code :(

Answer (score -1):

Taking Initial variables as -1 and 1 is MUCH MORE Advantageous, than taking them as 0 and 1.

The C code for Fibonacci Series(10 elements):-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a=-1,b=1,x=0,i;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        x=a+b;
        printf("%d\n",x);
        a=b;
        b=x;
    }
}
```

This JavaScript Code, works for all Positive integer values of n:-

```
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
var fibNumSequence = [];
var n1 = -1;
var n2 = 1;
var nextTerm=0;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
    nextTerm = n1+n2;
    fibNumSequence.push(nextTerm);
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = nextTerm;  
    }
return fibNumSequence;
}

fibonacciGenerator(n);
```

Comment: _Why_ is it “much more advantageous”?

Comment: Because, if you take n1 as 0 and n2 as 1, and suppose the user wants only 2 terms to be printed, you will have to print n1 and n2. With the code i have shown, it works for all possible values of n(positive integer). There are no extra modifications required.

Comment: You should definitely dry run both versions, and you will definitely see the advantage yourself. if, after trying, you are unable to understand, feel free to comment and ask your doubts

Comment: Yours is the only one that worked, out of all the solutions provided. I was wondering if you could achieve the same result taking 0 and 1 as initial variables. @sukhbir1996. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes of course we can achieve same results if we use 0 and 1 as initial variables, but, extra code needs to be written to tackle special cases(when value of n is 1 or 2). Hence, we can avoid writing bulky code with a nice substitute of -1 and 1 as initial variables..

Also, it is very important to observe that in your code(in the question), you had not initialized the variable nextTerm. In my answer, I have initialized it to 0. You made a very small mistake, but it will be virtually impossible to find bugs like that. So be careful..